# Can I use delegates directly in a discriminated union in F#?

Tags: f#

I have the following:

```
type CallbackString = delegate of string -> unit
type CallbackByte = delegate of byte[] -> unit

type CallbackType =
| String of CallbackString
| Byte of CallbackByte
```

since I may have a lot of types adding up, is there a syntax to do something similar to this (that compiles that is):

```
type CallbackType =
| String of (delegate of string -> unit)
| Byte of (delegate of byte[] -> unit)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is API being used entirely from F#, you can avoid making delegates and use functions as first class values directly:

```
type CallbackType =
| String of (string -> unit)
| Byte of (byte[] -> unit)
```

If this is going to be used from C# and you want specific delegate types, an alternative would be to use the predefined `Action` and `Func` delegates in the System namespace types to handle this:

```
// Assumes 
// open System

type CallbackType =
| String of Action<string>
| Byte of Action<byte[]>
```

Comment: it is purely F#; Without using the delegates, if I have a function like : MyFunc (callback : CallbackType) = ..., and I have a function A myString : unit = ..., I can't do directly MyFunc A, right?

Comment: @Thomas You need to make the CallbackType, but otherwise, it should work fine - see https://try.fsharp.org/#?code=C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNYBVzQLwCwAUAD5QDKwATgJYB2A5lAPYBmUAFAM7X1MC0APigBXOjWABKYmQCSdYC3Yd6ioaPFTixBBEUBbEADExaTmkQp0GKAC5Yl1JhyRJUQkSheo+uMDQAFlAWSE42AO4SAcTeUGSUtIxQXKx0UOopaQBEIboAJlCRwEE8iQxZMd5yClA0qenCdWkALABM2kQ6esn1XO5QYInA9VnwSBAFpXz2AKRcWcldik21-YOqI2P5tQqzNAs0HYYmdGYcCXw9dNKdRE0ywvKK3g8+xqbEQA&html=DwCwLgtgNgfAsAKAAQqaApgQwCb2ag4CdMTJcMABwFp0BHAVwEsA3AXgCIBhAewDsw6AdQAqAT0roOSAMb9BAzoIAeYAPThoAbhkhMAJwDOJNgzAAzagA4OeQhqy5EhAEY9sYu6mBq3HvD6asEA&css=Q